# How to check the (empty) value of a input type="date" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, input

I want to check if the user entered a date. 
 But I can't figure it out how to do it.

Here's some javascript code what i already got but doesn't work :

```
var valueDate = document.getElementById('Date').value;
if ( valueDate== null || valueDate== '')
{
    alert('Date is empty');
    return false;
}
```

And the HTML `<input type="date" name="Date" id="Date"/>`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could check for a falsy value:

```
if (!valueDate) {
    // ...
}
```

The falsy values in JavaScript are:

1. `undefined`
2. `null`
3. `false`
4. `""`
5. `0` and `-0`
6. `0n`
7. `NaN`

Since `document.getElementById('Date').value` is always of type string if a value is set, you don't get false positives like `0` being treated like no input, which would be the case if the type was `number`.

Comment: Doesn't work. In chrome a calendar pops up where you can choose a date, and the standard value is dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: @Bas Have you actually tried it? This fiddle is working perfectly fine for me (play around with the control and look at the console output): http://jsfiddle.net/Zb28D/1/

Comment: i'm sorry I did something wrong. It does work now:-) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 11):

I would try using Date.parse() if I were you.

```
var valueDate = document.getElementById('Date').value;

if(!Date.parse(valueDate)){
  alert('date is invalid');
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp

Comment: Solution from Tr1stan is better, since you are testing for valid date too.

Comment: I didn't even know that `Date` had the `parse` method! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this

```
var valueDate = document.getElementById('Date').value;

if (!valueDate) {
  alert('date is invalid');
}else{alert('date is valid')}
```