# Validation code for Jquery datepicker when checking out

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have implemented a Jquery Datepicker on our site, but the customer can proceed to check out without choosing a date. can someone help me with a code?

should be like:
when the customer presses 'checkout' there should be an error that says 'please choose a date'.

this is the code in the snippet so far.

```
{{ '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" defer="defer"></script>

<div style="width:300px; clear:both;">
  <p>
    <label for="date">Kies uw bezorgdag:</label>
    <input id="date" type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly" value="{{ cart.attributes.date }}" />
    <span style="display:block" class="instructions"> Uw bestelling wordt in de avond tussen 17:30-22:00u bezorgd.</span> 
  </p>
</div>

<script>
  if (window.jQuery) {
  let $ = window.jQuery;

  $(function() {
    // Dates to exclude
    var excludeDays = ['2021-09-04', '2021-09-12'];

    function disableSpecificDate(date) {
      // To disable specific day
      var dateArr = [String(date.getFullYear()), String(date.getMonth() + 1), String(date.getDate())];
      if (dateArr[1].length == 1) dateArr[1] = "0" + dateArr[1];
      if (dateArr[2].length == 1) dateArr[2] = "0" + dateArr[2];
      return excludeDays.indexOf(dateArr.join("-")) == -1;
    }
    $("#date").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      minDate: +1,
      maxDate: '+1M',
      beforeShow: function() {
        // To exclude next business day after 12 PM
        if (new Date().getHours() >= 12) {
          $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", +2);
        }
      },
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [((day == 0 || day == 2 |day == 3 || day == 5 || day == 6) ? false : disableSpecificDate(date)), ''];
      }
    });
  });
```

i have searched on stack overflow but couldnt find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the (empty) value of a input type="date" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110663/how-to-check-the-empty-value-of-a-input-type-date-in-chrome)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the thing i do not understand is that the code has to communicate with the checkout button, i couldn't find that in the code you suggested. we are using Shopify.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75037725/edit) to show the checkout button.